# Copy from multiple sheets and paste into sheet 1

Tags: vba, loops, copy, copy-paste, worksheet

I am trying to get data from multiple worksheets and paste into sheet 1 but my code isnt working properly. It keeps copying from the sheet "table 1" over and over again. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Table 1" Then

            ActiveSheet.Range("A15:X35").Select
            Selection.Copy

            Worksheets("Table 1").Activate

                For i = 1 To 5000

                    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 1)) = True Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    Exit For
                    End If

                Next i

        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, you are copying from the `ActiveSheet`, not from `ws`. if the activeSheet is "table 1" (in fact, you activate table 1 yourself in the statement `Worksheets("Table 1").Activate`), then of course if will keep copying from it.

Besides, it is always better to copy directly from ranges without using Activate  and Select. I guess this is what you want to do:

```
With Worksheets("Table 1")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Table 1" Then
            For i = 1 To 5000
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 1)) Then
                    ws.Range("A15:X35").Copy .Cells(i, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Saved my life. It works perfectly

Comment: @TobyKim You are welcome. Glad it helped :). Please dont forget to check the answered button to close the topic.

Comment: I have been looking for the answered button but i cant find it.. first time user

Comment: @TobyKim please take a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work